# Macro Deployment?

Tags: data-loader, data, macros

We brought someone in to develop a couple Macros. They work great, now we want to go live, and I've hit some roadblocks. I needed to do some post-processing to data load the related data. Just a `VLOOKUP` for the `MacroId`. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient route there but that's peripheral at best to the question.

When I tried to run the insert on `MacroInstruction`, 2 of 10 records failed. One said:

> Target: bad value for restricted picklist field: Field.Case.Status

Wait a minute! I looked at the record that threw this error and the `Value` is `'Pending'`, which is in the list. I ran this snippet to confirm:

```
Set<String> statusValues = new Set<String>();
for (PicklistEntry entry : MacroInstruction.Target.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
    statusValues.add(entry.getValue());
system.assert(statusValues.contains('Pending'));
```

Somewhat confused, I looked at the other error:

> Target: bad value for restricted picklist field: QuickAction.Case.Update_Status

So I thought, hmm, maybe the `Target` field is  a restricted picklist. Indeed, it is, and it only has five entries that have anything to do with `Case`. Neither of the `QuickAction` options correspond to any `API Name` under `Buttons, Links, and Actions` for `Case`.

```
for (PicklistEntry entry : MacroInstruction.Target.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
    system.debug(entry);
```

Relevant log:

> Schema.PicklistEntry[getLabel=Active Issue Tab;getValue=Tab.Case;]
>   Schema.PicklistEntry[getLabel=Body;getValue=Field.CaseComment.CommentBody;]
>   Schema.PicklistEntry[getLabel=Body;getValue=Field.CaseComment.CommentBody.cursor;]
>   Schema.PicklistEntry[getLabel=Community Action;getValue=QuickAction.Case.CaseComment;]
>   Schema.PicklistEntry[getLabel=Email Action;getValue=QuickAction.Case.Email;]

**How is the `MacroInstruction.Target` picklist populated? Do we have any control over it?**

I opened a case, just curious if anyone's run into this issue before or has better knowledge than what I can find digging around.

Comment: I see mention of Community in your log. Might this be a permissions issue in your production org?

Comment: Maybe...But what permissions do you even check for that? It also looks like it's just the label for the `CaseComment` action.

Comment: Was mostly an observation. Profiles and permissions frequently vary between sandboxes and production. Ditto for sharing on the most obtuse of things. I've no real clue as to what you should look for (don't know what license or sharing model you're using), but when something is exposed to a Community, that's often the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if your `MacroInstruction` references a `QuickAction`, it must be included on a `Page Layout` somewhere. The guy who set up our `Macros` didn't take the time out to dig through our `Setup Audit Trail` to decipher his changes. Anyway, I added the `QuickAction` to a `Page Layout` and the deployment went through. Not sure how that relates to the restricted picklist field error...but the instructions went through.